# Twilio hanging up after 45 minutes

Tags: twilio

I'm a newby using twilio to play an audio recording of the Sunday service for those people who do not have internet access.  They dial a number, get a message to hang on, then the application plays an audio file of the service.  Seems to work well, EXCEPT that for many users, the system hangs up on them after approximately 45 minutes into the 55 minute service.

Based on the logs, the hang-up seems quite consistent.  Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing that is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the documentation for the `<Play>` element, under ["Hints and Advanced Uses"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#hints), it says:

> `<Play>`ing a file that is longer than 40 minutes can result in a dropped call. If you need to `<Play>` a file longer than 40 minutes, consider splitting it up into smaller chunks.

I'd advise splitting the service up into two chunks of 27.5 minutes and playing them one after another, to avoid this issue.